# Incorporate RESULT_CACHE function into a Query

Tags: sql, oracle, database-performance

I want to incorporate a RESULT_CACHE function into following query

```
  select 
         a,
         b
  from
      ( select x,y, row_number() over (partition by x ) rank from table )
  where
        rank = 1
```

The reason being if the function is called for same value of X, it will get data from RESULT_CACHE and not hit the tables.

Comment: Are columns `a` and `b` on the table?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the the Result Cache configured the following hint should look to the Result Cache

```
select /*+ RESULT_CACHE */
     a,
     b
from
  ( select x,y, row_number() over (partition by x ) rank from table )
where
    rank = 1
```